# PROBLEMA CON ENLACE EN PLANTILLA WORDPRESS ATTORNA

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

actualmente estoy teniendo problemas con el botón de un enlace ya que no me está redirigiendo a la página que indico en el formulario de la plantilla. Es como si no agarrara el enlace que guardo en la plantilla y no queda funcional el botón...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El fragmento del código del header, donde creo que es el error, es el siguiente pero no logro solucionarlo.

```
$logo_right_button_icon = attorna_get_option('general', 'logo-right-button-icon');
        $logo_right_button_text = attorna_get_option('general', 'logo-right-button-text');
        $logo_right_button_link = attorna_get_option('general', 'logo-right-button-link');
        $logo_right_button_link_target = attorna_get_option('general', 'logo-right-button-link-target', '_self');
        if( !empty($logo_right_button_text) && !empty($logo_right_button_link) ){
            $logo_right_text .= '<a class="attorna-logo-right-button" href="" ';
            $logo_right_text .= ' href="' . esc_attr($logo_right_button_link) . '" ';
            $logo_right_text .= ' target="' . esc_attr($logo_right_button_link_target) . '" ';
            $logo_right_text .= '>';
            $logo_right_text .= empty($logo_right_button_icon)? '': '<i class="' . esc_attr($logo_right_button_icon) . '" ></i>';
            $logo_right_text .= gdlr_core_text_filter($logo_right_button_text) . '</a>';


    // menu right button
            if( $enable_right_button ){
                $button_class = 'attorna-style-' . attorna_get_option('general', 'main-navigation-right-button-style', 'default');
                $button_link = attorna_get_option('general', 'main-navigation-right-button-link', '');
                $button_link_target = attorna_get_option('general', 'main-navigation-right-button-link-target', '_self');
                echo '<a class="attorna-main-menu-right-button ' . esc_attr($button_class) . '" href="' . esc_url($button_link) . '" target="' . esc_attr($button_link_target) . '" >';
                echo attorna_get_option('general', 'main-navigation-right-button-text', '');
                echo '</a>';
            }
```

¿Alguien me podría orientar qué error tiene el código? ¡Mil gracias!

Comment: Que error te da? que es lo que aparece cuando das a inspeccionar el elemento? puedes poner SS de lo que se muestra en tu código fuente y en la consola de desarrollador? (F12)

Comment: NO GRITES EN LAS PREGUNTAS NI EN LAS RESPUESTAS. Como puedes ver, no se lee bonito. Evita las mayúßculas sostenidas

Answer (score 1):

no te preocupes. Ya pude arreglar el error.

Para el que también utilice el tema de attorna en worpress el error estaba en la siguiente línea:

```
   $logo_right_text .= '<a class="attorna-logo-right-button" href="" '
```

la reemplacé por

```
   $logo_right_text .= '<a class="attorna-logo-right-button" '
```

suprimiendo con ello la etiqueta de href que hacía que no me llevara a ningún enlace que guardaba en la plantilla.

Feliz día.

Comment: Por favor no utilices el area de respuestas para realizar comentarios, si quieres agregar nuevo contenido lo mejor es ir a  [edit] para actualizar tu pregunta.

Comment: Súper! Recuerda que la puedes marcar como aceptada en unas horas :)